# Is there a waiting room in the new Quantum Leap?

Tags: quantum-leap-2022

I just started watching the new Quantum Leap series, but as far as I can tell, there's been no mention of what happened to Ben's original body - or if there is a continuation of the Waiting Room concept from the original series.

Since this is a sequel of the original series, not a complete reboot, I would expect the Waiting Room to still be a thing. Unless Ben's "changes" to the project somehow resulted in a Waiting Room no longer being necessary.

I admit I'm only three episodes in, so there might still be an explanation of the Waiting Room coming. But it's also possible I missed it.

Is there a Waiting Room with Ben's body in the new series? If not, why?

Comment: Haven't seen it but is it really a sequel?  That seems to be more of a claim from the pitch meeting than finished product- at least from commercials.

Comment: It's definitely a sequel/continuation. Sam and Al are explicitly mentioned on several occasions and without too much spoilage, Al's family is featured as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[No](https://www.denofgeek.com/tv/quantum-leap-future-sam-beckett/)

> “There’s a scientific quantum principle called the law of superposition where two entities can hold the same time and space at the same time,” Wynbrandt explains, although this is a storytelling solution as much as a scientific one. “We personally felt the waiting room was a little difficult to wrap our minds around, so we’re actually moving on from it.”

I have since learned that [Wynbrandt is no longer the showrunner](https://deadline.com/2022/07/quantum-leap-martin-gero-showunner-dean-georgaris-exec-producer-steven-lilien-bryan-wynbrandt-1235076811/), so this reasoning may not stand in the future.

> There is behind-the-scenes shakeup on NBC’s new drama series Quantum Leap starring Raymond Lee. Martin Gero, who has served as EP on the project since the development stage, has stepped in as new showrunner. Dean Georgaris also has joined the series as executive producer on the reboot of the popular 1990s sci-fi drama. Gero is taking over showrunning duties for Steven Lilien and Bryan Wynbrandt, who wrote the pilot and will remain on the show as executive producers.

For what it is worth, some fans have speculated that [the code changes uploaded to Ziggy have resulted in the leaping working differently](https://www.reddit.com/r/QuantumLeap/comments/xiyyh2/comment/ip6b4n5/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) for this show.

Comment: In fairness, the waiting room was rarely addressed in the original show. Except for a couple of episodes.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots If that's true, then why does Ben only have the physical attributes of the hosts that his consciousness inhabits? Shouldn't his strength, agility, resistance to disease, vitality, and all of his other attributes be "added to" the host body that his mind possesses?

Comment: @Valorum: Looks like [8 episodes](https://quantumleap.fandom.com/wiki/Waiting_Room)

Comment: @Valorum The episode where Al from the 1990s, talks to his younger self from the early-1960s, in the Waiting Room, is one of the most epic and celebrated in the entire original series. So, I would say that the new series should explain why there is no longer a Waiting Room. There are a multitude of different ways that the writers could do this.

Comment: No, no, no! The law of superposition is from geology and is used for dating. The superposition principle is from quantum mechanics and does not have a relationship with two macroscopic entities existing in the same place and the same time: it says that a system has a state that exists as a sum of all its possible states. It says that an electron can be in a sort of indeterminate combination of up and down spins in a given direction. In fact, the Pauli exclusion principle, which relies on superposition, is a major part of the reason that two macroscopic objects cannot be in the same place!

Comment: Although electromagnetic repulsion is probably more important, the Pauli exclusion principle creates the election degeneracy pressure that prevents, say, white dwarf stars from collapsing.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Mentioned in 3, plus a major setpiece in two multi-part episodes

Comment: Yeah, the Waiting Room wasn't really that difficult of a concept to understand.